# cx_freeze and scipy: "ImportError: cannot import name vode"

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, cx-freeze

i am trying to create an executable from my python script. My script runs fine, but after freezing it, starting the .exe gives me the following error:

http://www.bild.me/bild.php?file=4663406scipyerror.png

I am using Python 3.2.3, Scipy 0.12.0b1, Numpy 1.7.0 and Matplotlib 1.2.0 (all 32bit).

Any ideas/hints on how to solve this? My guess is i have to include something manually in my freezing script, but i am running out of guesses :-(

I got it finally to work, but I am very unsatisfied with my solution:

1) copy `_odepack.pyd` and `odepack.py` from the SciPy package to my program folder

2) in `odepack.py` change `from . import _odepack` to `import _odepack` (otherwise `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package` is raised)

3) in my main change `from scipy.integrate import odeint` to `from odepack import odeint`

Now it is working as expected and after using cx_freeze it is still working.
Still got no idea why it would not work before :-(

Thanks ThomasK for pushing me in the right direction though :-)

Comment: What is line 25 of your script? What form is the vode module in, and can you find it anywhere in the build directory? Are you definitely using the latest version of cx_Freeze?

Comment: @ThomasK
Line 25 is the import
`from scipy.integrate import odeint`.

In the build directory there is scipy.integrate._odepack.pyd, which is copied from the scipy/integrate folder. 

I am using cx_freeze 4.3.1, which seems to be the newest version.

Comment: But there isn't a `scipy.integrate.vode.pyd` file? Is there any `vode.pyd` file on your system? If there is, try copying it next to the exe.

Comment: I copied `vode.pyd` from the `scipy.integrate` folder next to the exe, no luck. Same with renaming it to scipy.integrate.vode.pyd (because all the *.pyd were renamed like this).

Comment: It's definitely still the same error message you're seeing? Puzzling.

Comment: Yes definitely the same error message. I am assuming somehow cx_freeze has some problems with some imports (inside the `odepack.py`)

Comment: Ah, wait, it needs a little Python module inside the zip file to load the extension. Can you [file a bug](https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issues?status=new&status=open) about it failing to include the necessary bits?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got around this vode-problem by specifying "scipy.integrate.vode" as an include in the cx setup-file. This resulted in a file "scipy.integrate.vode.pyd" to end up in the build folder. I am using SciPy 0.11, Python 3.2.3 and the latest cx on Windows.

But adding such a "scipy.integrate.vode" file manually to the build folder would not fix the problem for me either, even though such manual-include-fixes were needed for many other .pyd files cx could not find either (and whereby the above setup.py include-solution would not work instead)...

Thanks for sharing your distress and wisdom, would not have managed to freeze my program otherwize...